# Eclipse - force Javadoc hover on element that has a warning

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I often look at the **Javadoc hover** that is shown when one hovers the mouse pointer over an element, as in this example for List.

[image]

However, when there is a warning present, the hover windows shows the warning instead as in this (fictional) example:

[image]

Imagine I could not fix the warning: Is there a shortcut to force to display the Javadoc hover *instead* of showing the warning?

Please note: I am aware of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> - Display javadoc in external browser, I am explicitly asking about the the hover.

Comment: You can use the shift, alt and control keys to change the effects of hoover, and you can also change what is shown in the preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while hovering will show you the Javadoc, even if there is a warning:

[image: screenshot]

As owlstead states in the comments, this behaviour can be adjusted by looking in the preferences:

[image: preferences screenshot]